# Occasionally Protractor fails to execute test using selenium grid 2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-grid

I've been experiencing some weird errors when launching my tests using selenium grid. Context: I've a lot of suites defined on my protractor-conf.js and use grunt launch tests on the pipeline. I've a selenium server working on my grid hub ('https://path:4444/wd/hub') which is responsible to forward the tests to 20 slaves that have chromedriver installed to run the tests. I don't have any kind of problem for the most part of the time, I am able to trigger this process with success and everything works fine. However, sometimes I get the following error:

```
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] Using the selenium server at http://path:4444/wd/hub

13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] 
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] /PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108

13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] var template = new Error(this.message);
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] ^

13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] UnknownError: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Read timed out

13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at new bot.Error (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:109:9)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at /PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:160:24
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (eval at (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1124:19), :1857:20)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (eval at (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1124:19), :2448:25)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (eval at (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1124:19), :564:12)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at Array.forEach (native)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (eval at (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1124:19), :553:15)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].goog.async.run.processWorkQueue as _onTimeout
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at Timer.listOnTimeout as ontimeout
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].Builder.build (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:445:22)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:38:7)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:182:37)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at driverprovider_.setupEnv.then.then.then.frameworkPath (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:263:21)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at _fulfilled (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at self.promiseDispatch.done (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
13:37:05 [chrome #1-4] at /PATH/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
13:37:05 
13:37:05 [launcher] Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
```

I must say that this happens with the same codebase of a successful execution. For instance, I push something to my pipeline, the tests run and everything passes. Then I restart the job with the exact same codebase/environment and that error occurs (the error can happen first and then disappears, this doesn't follow a specific rule). I can provide more information if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Luis, I'm having the same problem has you. Did you find any fixing for this ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gilherme, I managed to solve it by reinstalling my slaves with the newest versions of protractor/selenium and it magically was solved...